# Uploading A File to a Sharepoint Online Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm trying and failing to upload a file to a Sharepoint Online Document Library using the C# graph sdk.

I can get the drive/library, but if I get it as a Drive, Root is null, and I get an exception.  If I address it as a List, I can't seem to use the CreateUploadSession method.

Getting the Doc Library as a list works:

```
await graphClient.Sites[SPUrl + ":"].Sites[SpPath + ":"].Lists[libId].Request().GetAsync();
```

Getting the Doc Library as a Drive by Drive ID doesn't seem to work:

```
var drive = await graphClient.Sites[SPUrl + ":"].Sites[SpPath + ":"].Drives[driveId].Request().GetAsync();
```

Getting the Doc Library as a Drive of its List does:

```
var drive = await graphClient.Sites[SPUrl + ":"].Sites[SpPath + ":"].Lists[libId].Drive.Request().GetAsync();
```

But trying to get the Root of that Drive results in "bad request: URL specified is invalid."  So does trying Drive.Items.Request().  But as far as I can tell, I need to have the Root of the drive to do this:

```
var uploadSession = await graphClient.Sites[SPUrl + ":"].Sites[SpPath + ":"].Lists[libId].Drive.Root.ItemWithPath(file.FileName).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync();
```

But I have three Document Libraries and they all show Root as null.  Clearly I'm missing something, but I'm not clear on what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, in case if site is [*addressed by server-relative URL*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#access-a-site-by-server-relative-url), the following query

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/{server-relative-path}:/drive
```

succeeds and returns default drive, while the following:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/{server-relative-path}:/drive/root
```

fails and returns the error `Url specified is invalid.`

It appears to be a **bug** with Microsoft Graph itself. 
Anyway the following option could be considered to upload a file into library.

> It is assumed `siteUrl` corresponds to site server relative url  and
>   `listId` to library unique identifier

It consists of the following steps:

- resolve site by server relative url
- access root folder for for a Library
- upload a file

Example

```
//1.resolve site by server relative url
var targetSite = await graphClient.Sites.GetByPath(siteUrl,hostName).Request().GetAsync();    //2.access root folder for for a Library
var targetFolder = graphClient.Sites[targetSite.Id]
       .Lists[listId]
       .Drive
       .Root;

 //3.Upload a file
 var pathToFile = @"c:\Temp\Guide.docx";
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {
      var uploadedItem = await targetFolder
        .ItemWithPath("Guide.docx")
        .Content
        .Request()
        .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream);
 }
```

where

- `hostName` is site collection hostname (e.g.
  `contoso.sharepoint.com`)
- `siteUrl` - server relative site url, e.g. `/sites/management`